# Without `return`, tuple is recognized as just parenthesis

Tags: rust

I was trying some code from [the tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/primitives/tuples.html).

I followed exactly what the tutorial did, a return statement without `return` and got the following error: `expected tuple, found ()`.

I added the `return`, then it works. What's happening?

```
fn reverse(pair: (i32, bool)) -> (bool, i32)
{
    let (a, b) = pair;

    return (b, a); // No error
    // (b, a); // Error
}

fn main() {
    let pair = (1, true);
    println!("Pair: {:?}", pair);
    println!("Reversed: {:?}", reverse(pair))
}
```

Comment: The compiler suggests you to remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `()` is a [unit type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.unit.html) in rust and it is used as a `nothing` type, similar to `void` in `c`/`c#`/`java`.

Adding a semicolon  the end of an experssion wil tell the compiler to disregard its value and resolve it to `unit`. So `(b, a);` has the type of `unit` when returning its value from the function.

Removing the semicolon will stop the suppression of the expression and return the tuples value.

```
fn reverse(pair: (i32, bool)) -> (bool, i32){
    let (a, b) = pair;
    (b, a)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you include the `;` (semicolon), it's treated as a complete statement. It will not automatically return the value you expect - it will return `()` (unit type). If you omit the semicolon, then it will return that value.

```
fn reverse(pair: (i32, bool)) -> (bool, i32)
{
    let (a, b) = pair;

    (b, a) // return value
}
```

The sample does omit the semicolon FYI.

Comment: The function is still automatically returning, its jus returning a [unit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.unit.html) because the semicolon is discarding the value of the tuple.

Comment: @pigeonhands clarified